# How to prevent spyder from crashing if there is too much data in list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, spyder

I am running the below code to get XML objects from an API in `Anaconda Spyder`. The XML objects appended in a list, keep getting larger. For some reason `spyder` keeps crashing, from what I believe is the list getting to large.

I have to make roughly ~300K api calls for which I need data from which I think is causing my application to crash because when I am appending into the list, there is too much data.

Below is code to call api and save results into list. `lst1` is a list of ids that I pass into the api. I have to take into account that if the http request times out or I can build a mechanism to clear the appended list of data, that I can restart the requests from the ID I left off at from `lst1` which is passed into the api url.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import time
from concurrent import futures

lst1=[1,2,3]

lst =[]

for i in lst1:
    url = 'urlId={}'.format(i)
    while True:
        try:
            xml_data1 = requests.get(url).text
            print(xml_data1)
            break
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print(e)
    lst.append(xml_data1)
```

I am thinking that if I can apply my below function to unpack the xml into a dataframe and perform the needed dataframe manipulation, while clearing the list of appended data `lst` that it could free memory. IF this is not the case, I am open to any suggestions to allowing code or application to not crash with what I believe is too much xml data in the list:

```
def create_dataframe(xml):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, "xml")
    # Get Attributes from all nodes
    attrs = []
    for elm in soup():  # soup() is equivalent to soup.find_all()
        attrs.append(elm.attrs)
    # Since you want the data in a dataframe, it makes sense for each field to be a new row consisting of all the other node attributes
    fields_attribute_list = [x for x in attrs if 'Id' in x.keys()]
    other_attribute_list = [x for x in attrs if 'Id' not in x.keys() and x != {}]
    # Make a single dictionary with the attributes of all nodes except for the `Field` nodes.
    attribute_dict = {}
    for d in other_attribute_list:
        for k, v in d.items():
            attribute_dict.setdefault(k, v)
    # Update each field row with attributes from all other nodes.
    full_list = []
    for field in fields_attribute_list:
        field.update(attribute_dict)
        full_list.append(field)
    # Make Dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(full_list)
    return df


with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:  # Or use ProcessPoolExecutor
    df_list = executor.map(create_dataframe, lst)

full_df = pd.concat(df_list)
print(full_df)


#final pivoted dataframe
final_df = pd.pivot_table(full_df, index='Id', columns='FieldTitle', values='Value', aggfunc='first').reset_index()
```

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) It's hard to help you without being able to run this code ourselves, but (as you said) you should be better by processing each xml response after they arrive, instead of adding them all to a list and the proceeding. You could even do that asynchronously because it seems processing each response is independent from the others. For that (I think) you could use [Dask bags](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/_downloads/daskcheatsheet.pdf).

Comment: @CarlosCordoba, thank you for the suggestion. Is there anyway you can give me an example of processing the xml after they arrive with the code I have? I will check out dask bags

Comment: Sorry, I don't have more advice to give.